# How to fill an excel sheet with data entered in a form and stored in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, excel, arraylist, apache-poi

I am working on a data collection app, so I have forms that the user fill with data and I want to export the data in an excel sheet where I have multiple rows, every row should be inserted after saving the form filled in the android app.I did store the data in an arraylist and insert it in excel file but it is just the first row that changes, I do not know how to iterate through rows in a way that every time I enter new data in the form new row will be inserted, not that the same row changes value.

int r=2; (start writing from the second row on excel sheet)
Here dataEditText is an arraylist where I stored the data retrieved from EditText of the form's fields.
So the problem I have is how that I cannot iterate through the rows, I just keep changing the value of the first row.
Thanks !

```
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r++);
                for (int j = 0; j < dataEditText.size(); j++) {
                    HSSFCell tempCell = row.createCell(j);
                    //tempCell.setCellValue(cursor.getString(i));
                    String tempValue = "";
                    tempValue = dataEditText.get(j);
                    tempCell.setCellValue(tempValue);
                    tempCell.setCellStyle(cellStyleBody);

                
                    row.setHeight((short) 800);
                }
```

Comment: `dataEditText` An EditText? And where is your ArrayList?

Comment: List<String> dataEditText = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String []{latitude, longitude, EditPrecision.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(dateTimeDisplay.getText()) , EditIdArmoire.getText().toString()}));

Comment: dataEditText is the ArrayList where I stored data entered by the user in the form,   for example EditPrecision is an editText, latitude also is EditLatitude.getText().toString()

Comment: `dataEditText is the ArrayList` Well sorry... you should start with giving that variable a better name.. `dataArrayList` ?

Comment: yes, I'll change it. Do you have any idea how to iterate through the rows to fill them with data ? Thanks